# Bluetooth pilot/remote control

Tags: android, linux, bluetooth

Is there any app that could be used as a simple remote control to trigger a command on my Beaglebone Black (or RPi or any other Linux system) via Bluetooth? I am looking for something very simple - either just a simple button or even no UI (as long as there is basic error management - eg info that action cannot be triggered if my BBB is not in range). I am ok if the pairing process is not trivial, but it should later be trivial to operate. It should also be relatively hard to spoof my remote and actually trigger the action for unauthorized users.

Comment: With BT it's often "who can sniff, can spoof" – and easily at that unless pairing is required. As for Raspis, maybe [my corresponding app list](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/remotedroid_singleboard#group_723) has a fitting candidate?

Comment: I am totally ok with pairing or whatever it takes to be at least moderately secure.